# After JSP Form Submit, UTF-8 Encoding Characters Shown with Ampersand (&#7726;)

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a Struts 1.3 application with forms where the input fields should support special characters.

In the JSP, UTF-8 is defined as the encoding charset. This is also in the rendered HTML.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I fill out the form and enter this string for one of the fields,

ëḮ

Then I submit the form and page gets re-displayed with the saved value. I see the following on redisplay:

```
ë&#7726;
```

The Struts ActionForm holds the URL version when I reach the Action class, but maybe I should decode it after the form is submitted?

Comment: Are you seeing `&#7726;` on the page or in the HTML source?

Comment: On the page. The page should show the real string.